# How can I extract a hex digit n from word x?

Tags: c

getHexDigit - Extract hex digit n from word x

- Digits numbered from 0 (least significant) to 7 (most significant)
- Examples: getHexDigit(0x12345678,2) = 0x6
- Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>

I'm confused because I don't understand how to extract and write only using those ops. Please help!!

```
    int getHexDigit(int x, int n) {

         return  (x >> (n >> 4)) & 0xff; // How do I fix this

        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I that because I thought it would help see my problem and fixing it would be easier. Maybe that wasn't right. I'm don't understand how I would do the above return.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
int getHexDigit(int x, int n) {
    return (x >> (n << 2)) & 0xf;
}
```

First, multiply `n` by `4` (by shifting left by 2-bits) because each hex digit is 4 bits, and then just take that group out by shifting right and masking with `0x0f`.

For example, see how it works for `getHexDigit(0x1234, 2)`:

```
bit pos           1 1 1 1  1 1
                  5 4 3 2  1 0 9 8  7 6 5 4  3 2 1 0  

(val)                   1        2        3        4
x               = 0 0 0 1  0 0 1 0  0 0 1 1  0 1 0 0

n = 2
n << 2 = 4

(val)                   0        1        2        3
x >> 4          = 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1  0 0 1 0  0 0 1 1

(val)                   0        0        0        3
(x >> 4) & 0x0f = 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please explain why it would in this way, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A single digit corresponds to 4 bits, such that you have to shift `n*4` bits right; So you have to multiply `n` by `4`, and since you must not use `n * 4`, you can simply write `n << 2`; shifting two bits left means `2*2`:

```
return  (x >> (n << 2)) & 0x0F;
```

Then you have to "unmask" all the digits except the one you want to have; Therefore the `& 0x0F`.

Comment: Hi, if I use just 0xf then it works rather than 0xff.

Comment: @R..: yes, `0xff` is wrong as it keeps up to two digits, not one. `0x0F` stands for 4 bits, i.e. one hex digit.